# rapidjson add object to particular index

Tags: android, iphone, cocos2d-x, rapidjson

I have an issue... 
I rapidjson library `PushBack (GenericValue &value, Allocator &allocator)` is add element to last index of array.

I want to add object at particular index in rapidjson.

please help me for this

Answer (score 2):

Well, there's no such method in rapidjson, AFAIK.
You have several options:

- You can write a function moving all elements out of the array (using `PopBack`) and then pushing them back while inserting the new element at the necessary index.
- You can keep the data in another structure (say, vector or deque) and convert it to JSON when you no longer need to modify it.
- You can extend the GenericValue and implement the insert method there.
- You can modify the GenericValue and implement the insert method there (then it would be nice if you submit a patch into the https://github.com/Tencent/rapidjson/issues).